# a really basic SML issue I just can't seem to figure out (small code)

Tags: sml, ml

Just a basic Casaer Cipher. I've tested all of the sub functions, just encryptChar() does not particularly work.  I get an infinite loop.  It's supposed to be recursive.  Here's the all code:

```
fun replace (str : string, index : int, newChar : char) : string = String.substring(str,0,index) ^ String.str(newChar) ^ String.substring(str,index+1,(size str) - index - 1;

fun encryptChar (msgStr : string, shiftAmnt : int, index : int) : string =   
    let val asciiCode = 0  
    in  
        if (not (String.sub(msgStr, index) = #" ")) then  
        (  
            asciiCode = ord( String.sub(msgStr, index) ) + shiftAmnt;  
            if (asciiCode < ord(#"A")) then asciiCode = asciiCode + 26  
            else if (asciiCode > ord(#"Z")) then asciiCode = asciiCode - 26  
            else asciiCode = asciiCode;  
            msgStr = replace(msgStr, index, chr(asciiCode))  
        )  
        else asciiCode = asciiCode;  
        index = index + 1;  
        if (index < (size msgStr - 1)) then encryptChar(msgStr, shiftAmnt, index)  
        else msgStr  
    end  
;  

fun encrypt(msgStr : string, shiftAmnt : int) : string = encryptChar (String.map Char.toUpper msgStr, shiftAmnt mod 26, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're misusing `=`. Outside of a variable definition, `=` is simply a boolean function which checks its arguments for equality. So if you do for example `asciiCode = ord( String.sub(msgStr, index) ) + shiftAmnt;`, it will simply return `false` (because `asciiCode` is not equal to `ord( String.sub(msgStr, index) ) + shiftAmnt`) and then throw that result away (because you have additional expressions after the `;`). It will not reassign `asciiCode`.

Variables in SML are immutable. If you want to emulate mutable variables you can use `ref`s and the `:=` operator. However I would not recommend that approach as it is generally not good functional style and not necessary in this case. The preferable approach would be to rewrite the code in a way that each variable is only assigned once.

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic indeed, and it's surprising that you ran into it in such a complicated situation.
Did you port this from some other language?

You need to forget everything you know about programming using assignments.

```
let val x = y in something
```

means more or less "within 'something', replace the identifier 'x' with the value of 'y'".
There is no way for you to change the value of x.

Do the substitution (this is not the actual evaluation order or anything, but it should give you an idea of what's going on):

```
   encryptChar("THIS", amount, 0)
```

=>

```
let val asciiCode = 0  
in  
    if (not (String.sub("THIS", 0) = #" ")) then  
    (  
        asciiCode = ord( String.sub("THIS", 0) ) + amount;  
        if (asciiCode < ord(#"A")) then asciiCode = asciiCode + 26  
        else if (asciiCode > ord(#"Z")) then asciiCode = asciiCode - 26  
        else asciiCode = asciiCode;  
        "THIS" = replace("THIS", 0, chr(asciiCode))  
    )  
    else asciiCode = asciiCode;  
    0 = 0 + 1;  
    if (0 < (size "THIS" - 1)) then encryptChar("THIS", amount, 0)  
    else str 
end ;
```

=>

```
        if (not (String.sub("THIS", 0) = #" ")) then  
        (  
            0 = ord( String.sub("THIS", 0) ) + amount;  
            if (0 < ord(#"A")) then 0 = 0 + 26  
            else if (0 > ord(#"Z")) then 0 = 0 - 26  
            else 0 = 0;  
            "THIS" = replace("THIS", 0, chr(0))  
        )  
        else 0 = 0;  
        0 = 0 + 1;  
        if (0 < (size "THIS" - 1)) then encryptChar("THIS", amount, 0)  
        else str
```

=>

```
        if (not (String.sub("THIS", 0) = #" ")) then  
        (  
            0 = ord( String.sub("THIS", 0) ) + amount;  
            if true then false
            else if false then false
            else true;
            false
        )  
        else true;  
        false;  
        if (0 < (size "THIS" - 1)) then encryptChar("THIS", amount, 0)  
        else "this"
```

->

```
        if (not false) then  
        (  
            false;
            false;
            false
        )  
        else true;  
        false;  
        if true then encryptChar("THIS", amount, 0)  
        else "THIS"
```

=>

```
        (  
            false;
            false;
            false
        )  
        false;  
        encryptChar("THIS", amount, 0)
```

=>

```
    encryptChar("THIS", amount, 0)
```

Which is where your infinite loop came from.

You would do well to get hold of an introductory text about ML programming.